# Django per-view based caching only for non-logged in users

Tags: django, caching

I am working with per-view based caching that Django provides. However I want to disable cache when the user is logged in. What is the best approach to achieve this from `urls.py` ?

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/cache/#the-per-view-cache

```
from . import views
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

urlpatterns = [
    path('', cache_page(60 * 15)(views.HomeView)),
]
```